# How to load H20 trained model in Java UDF

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, xgboost

I am trying to load trained xgboost model to be used in custom UDF written in Java. File is in zip format and stored in hdfs.

I have tried to read it using Path class but it's not working.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;

public EasyPredictModelWrapper loadModel(String xgBoostModelFile) {
        if (model == null) {

            synchronized (_lockObject) {
                if (model == null) {
                    log.info("Model has not been loaded, loading ...");
                    try {
                        Path path = new Path(xgBoostModelFile);
                        model = new EasyPredictModelWrapper(MojoModel.load(path)); // Doesn't compile since MojoModel only takes string as an input.
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        log.error("Got an exception while trying to load xgBoostModel \n", e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return model;
    }
```

I Want to successfully load model.zip

Answer (score 0):

Got answer in H20 slack community.

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
Path path = new Path(xgBoostModelFile);
FSDataInputStream inputStream = fs.open(path);
MojoReaderBackend mojoReaderBackend = MojoReaderBackendFactory.createReaderBackend(inputStream,CachingStrategy.MEMORY);
model = new EasyPredictModelWrapper(MojoModel.load(mojoReaderBackend));
```